# advantages of separated DB in docker?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

case 1 : django+postgresql (container)

case 2 : django(container)<-connect->postgresql(container)

(these cases are on one server)

What are the advantages of separating ? or performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage of using second case are as follows:

- You can use load balancer in the future and deploy multiple django apps which connect to central DB.
- You don't need to worry if any developer does any docker file mishap, because your django app would only be hampered not the database
- Upgrading database server would not hamper the django server.
- You would have a decoupled approach rather than tightly coupled.

When you should use first approach with single docker with postgres and django:

- You are building hobby project
- You don't want to get into the details and intricacy to work with multiple docker and just focus on coding on django.

Comment: thanks! second case advantage is easy to scale out and focus on django server but disadvantage is costs for connection (network) right??

Comment: yes . And also you need to learn docker much more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

Note: one project which is *not* an hobby project is [Omnibus GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/)

> Omnibus is a way to package different services and tools required to run GitLab, so that most users can install it without laborious configuration

It is *one* [giant docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/docker/README.html), with a [Dockerfile including](https://github.com/gitlabhq/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/docker/assets/setup#L43-L50):

- NGiNX
- Redis
- PostgreSQL
- Prometheus
- Consul

Whenever those services are tightly coupled together, it can make sense keeping a monolithic model.

But even there, you have the choice to [connect to an external database (Ie. "non-packaged PostgreSQL database"](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/database.html#using-a-non-packaged-postgresql-database-management-server), the advantage being the administration associated with it (backup/restore) can be delegated to that external service.

If you use the pre-packaged one, you are sure to have the right version, but you will have to manage the backups yourself.